Difference between Apple Sign-In Token Request: /auth/token vs /auth/keys
I am working on a Flutter + Django REST Framework application and implementing Apple Sign-In functionality. When Iam tried to manually obtain the user's access_token, I followed the flow where needed to generate a client_secret on the backend (it was a JWT built using values like KEY_ID, TEAM_ID, CLIENT_ID, and CLIENT_SECRET from APPLE DEVELOPER account). I would then send the authorization_code (received from flutter), client_secret(genereted by developer on backend), and other details to https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token to get the access_token.
However, when integrating the same Apple Sign-In functionality using the drf-social-oauth2 library for Django, I noticed that I no longer need to use all those keys and secrets (like KEY_ID, TEAM_ID, CLIENT_SECRET etc.). Instead, it only requires the CLIENT_ID and identity_token that I receive from the Flutter app, and it sends a request to https://appleid.apple.com/auth/keys, which returns the access_token without needing the authorization_code from Flutter.
So, what is the difference between these approaches? In both cases, I get an access_token (although access_tokens have different expiration times), but the only thing is that in one case, I don't need all those keys, and in the other, I do.

If the user completes the Sign in with Apple process on their device, then the on-device libraries take care of all of the interactions required to generate a signed access token.
The https://appleid.apple.com/auth/keys endpoint doesn't return a token, it simply returns the keys that are required to validate that the token that was provided by your flutter app was signed by Apple. Once the OAuth process has the required key and has validated the token you can use it.
However, the access token will eventually expire.  One way of obtaining a new access token is to require the user to re-authenticate, but this can be disruptive to the user.  The other method is to use a refresh token.
The authorization_code can be used with the https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token endpoint to obtain a refresh token via an authorization_code grant request.
Your server can securely store the resulting refresh token and use it with the token endpoint to obtain both new access tokens and new refresh tokens without requiring user authentication via a refresh_token grant request.
